# Code: "Request.Cookies" is invalid when typing c# in my html file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm trying to obtain the value of a cookie, and based on that display different links in the navbar on top of my page. This is an ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 application. I'm getting an error that the word `Request` is not valid in this context. Is there a way to get that code working, or is different code needed to get that value? In my startup file, I have the code: `app.UseCookiePolicy();`

```
<li class="nav-item">
    @{string signedUp = Request.Cookies["signedUp"]; } 
 
    @*if user's first time, show signup link, otherwise, then the if else below...*@

    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOut">Log Out</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogIn">Log In</a>
    }
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The razor page has the `HttpContext` and the `Request` is the part of the `Context`:

```
@{ string signedUp = Context.Request.Cookies["signedUp"]; }
```

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.request?view=aspnetcore-3.1)